# Mass Effect 3 Prizes

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, me3missions

Unless we've contacted you about an ordering or shipping problem, the orders have all been placed and you should be receiving your prizes soon. The only exception is for the Messenger Bag - Razer is temporarily out of stock. However, we were able to preorder them for when they restock, and they will ship as soon as they are available again. I don't know an exact time frame, but I will post an update here when I find out.

I apologize for not sending individual confirmation emails - there were just a lot of orders to track for this contest! (which is awesome)

Please let me know if you don't receive your prize within the next couple of weeks so I can look up your tracking information.

Thanks again for participating!

**Edit**: Just got an order update from Amazon, and the new estimated ship date for the Messenger Bags is May 30th! Much better than the previous estimate of May 31 - July 12. I still can't guarantee when they'll arrive of course, but this is good news!

Comment: Thank you, got my prize yesterday :)

Comment: I got my prize, you guys are TEH AWESUMZ!

Comment: Yay! Glad you guys are starting to receive them :)

Comment: I got mine yesterday in a crazy blue bag, thanks!

Comment: Got mine today. Normally Amazon takes weeks to ship to Singapore! The headphone look awesome, thanks so much!

Comment: Any ETA on the messenger bags or did Razor take SE's money and run?

Comment: @Ktash the estimated ship date is May 31, 2012 - July 11, 2012. Clearly not very helpful, but there's nothing we can do besides wait at this point. From now on I'll preorder prizes in case they go out of stock. I'm sorry I can't do better this time.

Comment: @Lauren Lol, that is a great ship window. So specific ;) And no worries, just wanted to check in with it. Having to wait months, sometimes years, for video games has certainly made me patient :)

Comment: @Lauren The package arrived the day after my birthday! Guess the backorder was good timing!

Comment: We planned it that way all along :) jk, but glad you got it finally!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that ended a long time ago.